# Using Excel Proper Function with exception | Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially I have multiple strings within my Excel Spreadsheet that are structured the following way:

```
JOHN-MD-HOPKINS
REC-PW-RESIN
```

I would like to use the proper function but exclude the part of the string that is within the dashes `(-)`.

The end result should look like the following:

```
John-MD-Hopkins
Rec-PW-Resin
```

Is there an excel formula that is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create your own VBA function to do this, that checks if there are two hyphens in the data, and if so converts the first and last words to proper case without touching the middle word, otherwise just converts the string to proper case.

Paste the following into a module within Excel:

```
Function fProperCase(strData As String) As String
    Dim aData() As String
    aData() = Split(strData, "-")
    If UBound(aData) - LBound(aData) = 2 Then   '   has two hyphens in the original data
        fProperCase = StrConv(aData(LBound(aData)), vbProperCase) & "-" & aData(LBound(aData) + 1) & "-" & StrConv(aData(UBound(aData)), vbProperCase)
    Else    '    just do a normal string conversion to proper case
        fProperCase = StrConv(strData, vbProperCase)
    End If
End Function
```

Then, in your worksheet, you can use this just as you would any built-in formula, so if "JOHN-MD-HOPKINS" is in cell A1, you would use this as a formula in another cell:

```
=fProperCase(A1)
```

Which would display `John-MD-Hopkins` as required.

**EDITED CODE**

As the requirement is to leave the second word, then this modified VBA function, which "walks" the array should work instead:

```
Function fProperCase2(strData As String) As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData() = Split(strData, "-")
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        If (lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) + 1) And (lngLoop1 <> UBound(aData)) Then
            aData(lngLoop1) = aData(lngLoop1)
        Else
            aData(lngLoop1) = StrConv(aData(lngLoop1), vbProperCase)
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    fProperCase2 = Join(aData, "-")
End Function
```

It basically looks to see if the array element being dealt with is the second (`lngLoop1=LBound(aData)+1`) and also not the last (`lngLoop1<>UBound(aData)`).

Regards,

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add an important requirement, this rule should only apply to the first set of dashes in the string. So for example `JOHN-JN-JAMES-MASON` = `John-JN-James-Mason`

Comment: I appreciate your help, do you know how this can be accomplished?